# Remotely launch, resize, reposition programs

Tags: windows, windows-7

We currently have a Windows server program that lets us launch a Windows application on a remote computer at any position on the screen and then reposition/resize/terminate that application remotely.  This remote control of individual applications is not visible on the remote computer, which is good, as we're using this program to control vlc instances on multiple huge monitors in different rooms.

This program is developed by a service company, who has been charging us exorbitant amounts of money per year for service plans and then charging additional money to perform software upgrades that often break the system for days at a time.

Long story short, I'm looking for an alternative solution.  Can anyone recommend a solution that will let me, from a central control application, remotely launch/position/size an individual application with minimal screen action/real estate on the remote computer?  This solution would have to work on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft SCCM 2007 and 2012 has the Remote Tools option, which lets anyone using the SCCM configuration manager to shadow clients without any notification (if you turn it off)

Depending on the licensing your organization is using, you may have some startup cost, (win svr 08 license, MS SQL svr license, etc..) but once implemented, would have no recurring costs besides replacing hardware.

You can run all the roles on a single machine, but may want to split the roles on to multiple pieces of hardware/VM's if you have a larger organization.